# Deploying Django at alwaysdata.com

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I am new on django. I tried this but I can't deploy. How can I do

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

base = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..'
sys.path.append(base)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myfirstapp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

---

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(cgi-bin/myproject.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you get errors? You are missing a + on line 5, and do you mean "../" instead of "/.." ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's the [alwaysdata wiki entry](http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/D%C3%A9ployer_une_application_Django) for setting up Django with fastcgi. Only down-side: it's written in French.

Well, I don't speak French, but what it basically says is:

1. Create a directory named `public` in the folder of your django project.
2. In that directory create the file `django.fcgi` with the following content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import os, sys

   _PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   sys.path.insert(0, _PROJECT_DIR)
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(_PROJECT_DIR))

   _PROJECT_NAME = _PROJECT_DIR.split('/')[-1]
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "%s.settings" % _PROJECT_NAME

   from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
   runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
   ```
3. Next, create a .htaccess in the `public` folder with the following content:

   ```
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
   ```
4. If you're planning to include the django admin interface, create this symbolic link in your `public` directory:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/alwaysdata/python/django/1.1/django/contrib/admin/media/ media
   ```
5. In the end your folder tree hierarchy should somehow look like this:

   ```
   myproject/
       __init__.py
       manage.py
       public/
           django.fcgi
           .htaccess
           media/
       settings.py
       urls.py
       myapp/
           views.py
           models.py
   ```

Hope this helps. I talked with the admin, and he said he will soon provide an English wiki. Let's hope this is going to happen anytime soon.

---

**UPDATE: There is an [English wiki article now.](http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Deploying_a_Django_App)**

Comment: +1 for delivering an answer about a system with docs written in a language you don't speak. Maybe there should be a new badge for this, just not sure what it would be called. Multilingual-nontranslating-wild-ass-guess-hackage? Nah, too long. :-)

Comment: AlwaysData is becoming more and more international everyday. I think that they would be very happy if you are ready to help for the english Wiki (it's a wiki so you can contribute). If the documentation is in french, the support is worldclass :)

Comment: This is still not working for me. When I visit my site I just get the Always Data default web page (~/www/index.html). How does the server know to run a Django/Python script?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to mix two different web server integration methods: fcgi (fast cgi) and wsgi.

Your first snippet is for a wsgi interface with the web server and is the recommended method for integrating Django with Apache.  Very good resources (including examples) to help you set this up correctly can be found in the official Django docs [How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#howto-deployment-modwsgi) and the mod_wsgi docs [Integration with Django](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango)

The second snippet (with AddHandler line) is for fcgi.  This is the kind of interface that is more typically used to interface Django with the lighttpd and nginx web servers.  Resources for setting up fcgi interface can be found in official Django docs [How to use Django with FastCGI, SCGI, or AJP](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/).

Since it looks like **alwaysdata.com** only uses FastCGI (fcgi) interface you are stuck with this method.  It looks like there are examples on their wiki page [Déployer une application Django](http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/D%C3%A9ployer_une_application_Django) and particulary you'll need to replace your first (wsgi) snippet with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

_PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, _PROJECT_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(_PROJECT_DIR))

_PROJECT_NAME = _PROJECT_DIR.split('/')[-1]
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "%s.settings" % _PROJECT_NAME

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Answer (score 2):

We got now (since a couple of months) an article in english: 
[Django on alwaysdata.com](https://help.alwaysdata.com/languages/python/django)

Regards,