# why my django site in hosting (alwaysdata) cant show my page

Tags: python, django, hosting

I have deployed Django at [alwaysdata.com](http://www.alwaysdata.com),

this is my main page on http://zjm1126.alwaysdata.net/ :

[image]

i change the `index.html` to `index1.html`, this file is not my file ,

my project is like this :

```
example_project/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    public/
        django.fcgi
        .htaccess
        media/
    settings.py
    urls.py
    myapp/
        views.py
        models.py
```

what can i do to show my main page .

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to point your subdomain to the right directory : `/example_project/public/` where your .htaccess and django.fcgi lives.

alwaysdata has a forum http://forum.alwaysdata.com/ where you can ask question in english. The guys know their job very well and answer very quickly.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconfigured server. It doesn't know that pages in that directory should by default should be handled by Python. This was covered in [Deploying Django at alwaysdata.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955189/deploying-django-at-alwaysdata-com).