# django hosting error , about alwaysdata.com

Tags: python, django, hosting, fastcgi

this is  my alwaysdata page - http://zjm.alwaysdata.net/:

[image]

It is not configured successful ,**but** when i Visit the http://zjm.alwaysdata.net/mysite/public/

it show  my main page :

[image]

so what can i do  to show my main-page on the http://zjm.alwaysdata.net/

thanks

**updated**

this is my `django.fcgi` :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

_PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, _PROJECT_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(_PROJECT_DIR))

_PROJECT_NAME = _PROJECT_DIR.split('/')[-1]
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "%s.settings" % _PROJECT_NAME

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

and `.htaccess` :

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    #(r'^$', homepage),
    # (r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Did you do what i've suggested here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435406/why-my-django-site-in-hosting-alwaysdata-cant-show-my-page/4436239#4436239

Comment: hi @luc, how to point my subdomain to the right directory  ??  look the updated , it is my file .

Comment: What is the content of your urls.py file?

Comment: @Seitaridis , look the updated .

Comment: Where is your first page located?

Comment: it is the django default page . i have not a page .

Comment: @zjm1126: You can configure this in the domains menu of the alwaysdata admin

Comment: excuse me, how did you activate the alwaysdata site? because I can login through ssh and ftp, but I get a cannot find server error. I read I have to activate the site in the admin somewhere, but I can't see how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your domain (`zjm.alwaysdata.net`) to point to your `/public` directory on the server : `/home/zjm/www/mysite/public/`